# Custom iPhone App Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Alright, this seems simple enough but I haven't found much documentation or posts regarding this. Basically, I want to have a completely custom tab bar at the bottom of my app. Being new to iPhone dev I thought I could do the following:

1. Place custom images on bottom of
   screen to act as tab buttons.
2. Create a UIView (lets call it
   "ContentView") to fill the rest of
   the screen that will display the
   appropriate tab's NIB. This
   "ContentView" is inside the main
   UIView for the NIB.
3. Hook up image "press" actions to the
   controller managing all this.

I'm not sure how I would go about loading the appropriate NIB into the "ContentView" with this method though. From the "Touch Up" action method in the controller can I dynamically load a NIB into that "ContentView" UIView?

Something about this whole thing makes me uneasy.
Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to dynamically load a nib at all. What are you trying to accomplish with this step? I would do the first three steps and then wire it up and call it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem I would create a nib with a UIView and its associated content in it. Connect the nib to a UIViewController. This will be the content of each tab. Create as many of these UIView-UIViewController combination as needed.

When the user touches a tab, create and load the UIViewController from the nib using

```
– initWithNibName:bundle:
```

Add the UIView in the nib to the main content view as a subview. Use

```
– addSubview:
```

As the user presses other tabs load the other nibs into memory and add their UIView into the main content view as a subview.

If a view is already in memory you can show and hide subviews with the following methods.

```
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
```

I think that would work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I was unaware of how the "addSubView" method would behave in this scenario.

This seems to be the a good solution in that tabs are only loaded when needed and are cached while not being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by,

either make different views with same tab bar image and custom button(load view on IBAction for button click:toucp up inside) or you can make different views for the same view(so you can hide views and show only one view at a time accordingly).

and you can load view (if you app is view based then add other views on window otherwise for navigation based app you need to pushViewController of navigation controller.

This is a tricky task but you need to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I think David's suggestion was more aligned with what I originally intended!